# undeclared identifier when making own procedure

Tags: delphi

Hey guys i don't know if this is kinda basic Delphi logic but my problem is as follows:

i'm trying to write a procedure called show i made an arry out of a text file and now i want my program to display that array in a richedit.

```
const
Damnaam = 200;
var
  Form1: TForm1;
  arrdam : array[1..Damnaam] of string;
  iTelDam : integer;
  Myler : Textfile;
implementation

{$R *.dfm}    


procedure  LIST;

begin
if FileExists ('Dam.txt') <> true then
 begin
 MessageDlg ('The file does not exist.',mtError,[mbOk],0);
 Exit;
 end;
 AssignFile(MyFile, 'Dam.txt');
 Reset (MyFile);
 while (NOT EOF (MyFile)) AND (icountDam < DamName) do
 begin
 inc(icountDam);
 readln(Myfile,arrDam[icountDam]);
 end;

end;

 procedure Show;
var
icount : integer;
begin
for icount := 1 to icountdam do
redoutput.lines.add(arrdam[icount]);
end;
```

it keeps giving the following error:

Undeclared Identifier: RedOutput
And I can't understand why.

Comment: Better read that text file with a `TStringList` which you can simply assign to the `RedOutput.Lines`. That `RedOutput` is probably supposed to be a memo or list box dropped on your form. I wish this old school I/O file handling disappear from the Internet.

Comment: Your code is really no good. You are going to need to stop using global variables. I suggest you start with a good beginners guide to programming.

Comment: Thanks for the feed back i'll see what i can do.

Comment: @TLama or at least in a code museum

Answer (score -1):

You must Declare redoutput object in global after you can use it in procedure

Comment: a did that now it says that redoutput might not have been initialized

Comment: Move the Show procedure in the TForm1 class. After that, just drop a TMemo component on that form and name it "RedOutput".

Comment: No. You didn't declare it global. You made it a local var, hence the warning. But you should not be using globals and it's poor that this answer advises you to do so. -1. What you need to do is learn. Random trial and error without knowledge won't get you far.